# I sent Monero to my wallet without it being fully synced

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

As the title says I sent myself some money to my Monero wallet without it being fully synced. Have I messed up and are my funds gone for good?

Comment: "Have I messed up and are my funds gone for good?" <- No, you won't have lost anything. Just follow the duplicate question's answer and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

do not worry wait to sync and check out